# How to access a field of the body of a post request that stores an array of files sent from postman to a Django server?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, postman

Sorry for the cumbersome question, but I am sending four files to a Django server using postman, and my goal is to access each file and get specific information about them, like their pathname and file size.

Here's the POST request on postman: [post_req_postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDrC9.png)

And here's how it looks like when the server receives the request: [request_printed_to_terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUmpc.png)

Basically, as shown in the screenshot and as I said, I want to access the following array in the `files` field of the request:

```
[<InMemoryUploadedFile: Screen Shot 2022-09-11 at 10.14.05 PM.png (image/png)>, <InMemoryUploadedFile: Screen Shot 2022-09-11 at 10.14.04 PM.png (image/png)>, <InMemoryUploadedFile: Screen Shot 2022-09-11 at 10.13.51 PM.png (image/png)>, <InMemoryUploadedFile: Screen Shot 2022-09-11 at 10.13.48 PM.png (image/png)>]}
```

Here's is the relevant Django code that handles the file uploads:

```
import io
import json
from operator import itemgetter
import os
from django.http import Http404,HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from google.cloud import storage
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "/Users/gabrieltorion/downloads/filestoragehelpusdefend-3082732cedb4.json"


class uploadFiles(APIView):
    payLoad = None
    print("Will listen for new file uploads")
    bucketMemoryMax = 400_000_000_000_00

    @csrf_exempt
    def post(self, request):

        storageClient = storage.Client()
        
        if request.data['name'] == 'uploadFiles':
            print("request.data: ", request.data)
            
            #the screen shots are in 'files'
            businessId, files = itemgetter("businessId", "files")(request.data)

            userBucket = storageClient.get_bucket(businessId)
            currentMemoryStorage = 0

            if userBucket:
                blobs = storageClient.list_blobs(businessId)
                if blobs:
                    for blob in blobs:
                        currentMemoryStorage+=blob.size

                if currentMemoryStorage < self.bucketMemoryMax:
                    # Get the length of the files
                    pass
                    
                    
                else:
                    return HttpResponse("Bucket is FULL. CANNOT UPLOAD FILES.", status=404)
        

        
        
        return HttpResponse("Post request is received.")
```

I tried the following to access the files in the body of the post request:

1. `print(files.file)` but that only gives me the following io.BytesIO object: `<_io.BytesIO object at 0x10b33c590>`
2. `print(files)` but that only gives me the path name of the last file in the Files array of the body of the request: `Screen Shot 2022-09-11 at 10.13.48 PM.png`

What am I doing wrong? How do I access the files and get their pathnames?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the list of files from the request object using `request.FILES.getlist('<key>')`.

Refer : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/file-uploads/

Answer (score 0):

You just need to write `request.data.getlist('field_name')` for getting the list of files.